# haxe - How to create clean terminal application in cpp environment?

Tags: terminal, console, stdout, haxe, utility

I'd like to create utility that should be able to listen standard input and stream to standard output. Moreover I'd like to get command line arguments passed to utility. Is it possible to do with haxe/cpp environment?

What "trace()" exactly do? Can I override it's auto CR/LF with some ascii control characters to print pseudographical activity gauges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the trace function is inteded to be used only for debug, i think that's why  it prints the file and the row from which you called it.

What I think you really want is `Lib.print()` and `Lib.printl()` to write something to the console.

For reading I didn't find a function as easy as that, but it's still easy enough, here's an example:

```
    var stdin  = Sys.stdin();
    var string : String = stdin.readLine();
```

If you want to look more into console development in haxe I'd suggest you to look into some projects that uses them, for example to write this question I've read this file https://github.com/ianxm/ihx/blob/master/src/ihx/ConsoleReader.hx

Comment: Thanks it works! But I've encountered one issue with running executable from FlashDevelop. After compiling and running this file with run.bat 'bin\mytool-debug.exe' or by direct call windows throws an error and suggests to debug it.When I run

Comment: what do you mean? anyway in the short tests that i did yesterday, sometimes it didn;t open the right .exe file, in that case open it yourself

Comment: When I run executable from command line it works fine. I've found that crash provoked by some functions like Sys.getChar() or Sys.systemName().